# Prefix command won't update MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py

So, I tried making a prefix command, I'm trying to get it to post to MongoDB when you do it, it won't work, can anyone help me?
I get no errors. :/

This is in a cog just letting you know.

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True, aliases=["prefix"])
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def changeprefix(self, ctx, prefix):

        post = {
                '_id': ctx.guild.id,
                'prefix': prefix,
                }
                
        await self.client.prefixes.upsert(post)
        await ctx.send(f'Prefix changed to: {prefix}')
        await ctx.guild.me.edit(nick=f"[{prefix}] «y e s bot»")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first have a entry into the database. I reccommend doing it like this:

```
guildExist = database.find_one({'_id': ctx.guild.id})
if guildExist == None:
    database.insert_one(post)
else:
    database.update_one({'_id': ctx.guild.id}, {'$set': {'prefix': prefix}})
```

This checks if the guild already is in the database, and if not it will add it.
Then if it already exists, it will update the prefix.

Overall the code should look something like this:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, aliases=["prefix"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def changeprefix(self, ctx, prefix):

    post = {
            '_id': ctx.guild.id,
            'prefix': prefix,
            }

    guildExist = database.find_one({'_id': ctx.guild.id})
    if guildExist == None:
        database.insert_one(post)
    else:
        database.update_one({'_id': ctx.guild.id}, {'$set': {'prefix': prefix}})

    await self.client.prefixes.upsert(post)
    await ctx.send(f'Prefix changed to: {prefix}')
    await ctx.guild.me.edit(nick=f"[{prefix}] «y e s bot»")
```